# Where to place line of code in html for ReactDOM.render?

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, reactive-programming

I have the following code which is in a saved format of .html (index.html).

I am learning React right now and when I execute this html file in the browser, nothing happens.

I am wondering where the two lines of code are suppose to go or how to call them (execute the rendering).

Where would I find the files in ./lib if I am using a mac?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Introduction | Learning React</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="entry-point"></section>

    <!-- Wifi might be spotty, so we've downloaded these to `./lib` -->
    <script src="lib/react.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/react-dom.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Intentionally blank. Your walk-through code will go here
      var hello = React.createElement('p', null, 'Hello, World!');

      // Checkout what this does by opening your HTML file in the browser
      ReactDOM.render(hello, document.getElementById('entry-point'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as long as you include the proper libraries:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Introduction | Learning React</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="entry-point"></section>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Intentionally blank. Your walk-through code will go here
      var hello = React.createElement('p', null, 'Hello, World!');

      // Checkout what this does by opening your HTML file in the browser
      ReactDOM.render(hello, document.getElementById('entry-point'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Using the correct setup ([JSX compiler](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html), e.g. Babel), you could simplify the above `createElement` to:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <p>Hello, World!</p>,
  document.getElementById('entry-point')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="entry-point"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I now understand it was the libraries I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use packet managers you can include React with CDNs.

For development:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

For production (minified):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```