# React in HTML, blank page

Tags: html, reactjs, react-dom

i have my react code in plain HTML

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="uttf-8">
    <title>React! React! React!</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        ReactDOM.render(
            <h1>Sherlock Holmes</h1>,
            document.body
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but he not work,  after run this index.html in Chrome i have only blank white page,
can someone explain me what i am doing wrong?

i use vscode

Comment: Is there any error reported in the console?

Comment: i don't use console, i run it by open in browser

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: i use Google Chrome

Comment: Do a right click on the page and select the `Inspect` option. This will open a window with many tabs right below the page. One of the tabs is Console. Click it

Comment: I have provided you with a solution. Kindly check it out and let me know if It has helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work, use the development version, not the production version of the react and react-dom files. Also note that you need to specify the type of your script as `"text/babel"` or babel won't parse it.

Check out the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
</head>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/babel">   /* notice type="text/babel"*/
    ReactDOM.render(
      <h1>Sherlock Holmes</h1>,
      document.body
    );
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**RESULT:** 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did react for the first time and it edited your code like that. I guess the two scripts I added are not needed, but just try it. As I understood you have to set an section to place the text. These two links could help too.

- [Where to place line of code in html for ReactDOM.render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418150/where-to-place-line-of-code-in-html-for-reactdom-render)
- https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_render.asp

My Code:

```
   <!Doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="uttf-8">
    <title>React! React! React!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <section id="entry-point"></section>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var h = React.createElement('p', null, 'Sherlock Holmes');
       ReactDOM.render(h, document.getElementById('entry-point'));
    </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```